# Passing Test Data file to a Selenium Script while executing it from command prompt

Tags: java, excel, selenium, jar

I have a functional automation script which fetches data from Test Data(excel file) and I used to run this script Eclipse GUI.

Now, what I have done is, I have exported my script to an Executable Jar file and running from Command Prompt(`java -jar <Filename.jar>`).

But with this approach I got stuck with the issue that whenever the data changes in Test Data file, I have to change in the actual file and export another jar file. With the huge change in data, this approach becomes hideous to me.

To eliminate this, I though of passing Test Data file(excel) path in the command while executing the jar and the script should pick the data from the specified file.

I did my research on this but all I got is dead ends. So, my question is "Is this approach doable?"

Comment: Don't know if this works, Move the Excel file out of the project (One level up in the directory structure) and read the Excel from there, so that excel files will not be included in the Jar file any more.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do, but the question is "How can I pass it to the command so that script will fetch the data?"

Comment: In the Code itself use the `relative path` of the excel file and build the jar. Place jar and Excel file in the correct path as declared in code (One level up) with the Jar.

Comment: Actually, this worked

Comment: When I am creating Jar, it does not hardcode the test data in the Jar file. It is taking from the relative path of the excel which I had placed long back and I was not aware of that.

You can post this answer, so that I can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the Excel file out of the project (One level up in the directory structure) and read the Excel from there, so that excel files will not be included in the Jar file any more and in the Code itself use the `relative path` of the excel file and build the jar. Place jar and Excel file in the correct path as declared in code (One level up) with the Jar.